# Invalid Identifier within a Trigger

Tags: plsql

I keep getting :
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEWROW"."ACCOUNT_NUM": invalid identifier

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

```
--OVERDRAFT TRIGGER

create or replace trigger overdraft_trigger 
after update on checking_acc
 REFERENCING NEW AS newrow
fOR EACH ROW

 when (newrow.balance < 0)

 Begin


  update checking_acc
 set overdraft_amount = newrow.balance
 where (newrow.account_num = checking_acc.account_num);



 end;
 /
```

see above

The trigger set the overdraft_amount to newrow.balance.

Comment: Trying to update the same tablet that is firing true trigger, within the trigger, is doomed to fail. Make it a before trigger and change the newrow values directly to whatever you want to commit. I'm struck though that this is so simple it doesn't need a trigger; how come you're using one?

Comment: A trigger is required for the assignment.  How can assign newrow values directly when it's a updated value?

Comment: Agree with Caius above, but also newrow requires a : in front of it, which is why you are getting the specific error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this as. BEFORE UPDATE trigger then you can just set the new values directly and they will be written to the table:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

--OVERDRAFT TRIGGER

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER overdraft_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE on checking_acc
fOR EACH ROW
WHEN (newrow.balance < 0)

BEGIN

  :new.overdraft_amount := :new.balance;

END;
```

You don't need the REFERENCING clause unless you want to rename the pseudorow

You don't prefix the NEW with a colon in the WHEN but you do prefix it with a colon in the body of the procedure

Avoid running select / insert / update /
delete statements that target the same table that is firing the trigger - you'll probably end up running into a "table is mutating, trigger may not see it" error if you do. Oracle is trying to indicate to you that the data you're referencing in the table might or might not have been changed and this could cause inconsistencies in your data

Avoid row level triggers if you can, as they are less performant than statement level triggers if lots of rows are being affected. Databases do things in bulk better and indeed some DB like SQLServer don't even have row level triggers which forces you to think of everything in terms of sets of data. At the end of the day most db's trigger implementations are very vendor specific. You'll also find that most DBAs have an overall dislike of triggers and will prefer to see code logic put into a stored procedure instead. Triggers can be handy for a quick fix where a bug is causing wrong data in a table but are generally avoided on production systems because they're relatively hidden/magic - developers forget about them and then spend time wondering why the values they sent to table x don't appear as sent

The fine manual has lots of great info on triggers - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm

There is also a more readable summary in the 2 day guide - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm